# filter rss feed based on URL/link

Tags: web-part, rss

I'm setting up an intranet that needs two RSS viewer webparts. But these webparts need to find specific content from the same feed!

It is this feed: http://www.skm.dk/rss

One webpart needs to show all entries with the url starting with: http://www.skm.dk/ministeriet/ministeriet/job/ledige-stillinger

The other webpart needs to show all other entries from the feed.

I've tried filtering directly in the feed URL (no success), I've tried using a filter webpart (can't get it to Work).

Any help?

Comment: Ended up having the feed split up instead. That was the easy and most viable solution.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up having the feed split up instead. That was the easy and most viable solution